# Dataclasses - AttributeError: type object 'Arguments' has no attribute 'column_names'

Tags: python, attributes, python-dataclasses, data-class

I am trying to use dataclasses to create a list of strings that can be used in a function. I am getting an attribute error when trying to access the information normally as I would with something like `my_int: Optional[int] = field(default=1000)`.

For example:

```
from typing import Optional, List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Arguments:
    """
    Configuration for data loader.
    """
    
    column_names: Optional[list[str]] = field(
        default_factory= lambda:['copies', 'path', 'repo_name', 'size', 'license', 'hash', 'line_mean', 'line_max', 'alpha_frac', 'autogenerated']
    )

def build_dl(args: Arguments):
    load_train_data = args.column_names
    return load_train_data

build_dl(Arguments)
```

**Error:**
AttributeError: type object 'Arguments' has no attribute 'column_names'

I am attempting to get `args.column_names` to be `['copies', 'path', 'repo_name', 'size', 'license', 'hash', 'line_mean', 'line_max', 'alpha_frac', 'autogenerated']`

I have not used dataclasses before. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to use `column_names` as a class variable, rather than a dataclass field. That is, in your case above you would need to first instantiate an instance of `Arguments` such as `Arguments(column_names=...)` to be able to access `column_names` attribute.

So to clarify, the quickest and easiest fix in your case would be to update the call like:

```py
build_dl(Arguments())
```

One other approach you can use to get around this is by using [class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#class-variables) as mentioned in the docs, which are excluded from consideration by `dataclasses` altogether. Another option can be to remove the annotation like `list[str]` entirely, which also achieves the same result.

In below I've also updated the annotation for `args` to `Type[Arguments]`, to indicate that we're passing the actual type (e.g. `Arguments`) rather than an instance of the same type.

```py
from typing import Type, ClassVar
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Arguments:
    """
    Configuration for data loader.
    """

    column_names: ClassVar[list[str]] = [
        'copies', 'path', 'repo_name', 'size', 'license', 'hash', 'line_mean',
        'line_max', 'alpha_frac', 'autogenerated'
    ]


def build_dl(args: Type[Arguments]):
    load_train_data = args.column_names
    return load_train_data


build_dl(Arguments)
```

Comment: You were correct in that it was as quick and easy as adding () to Arguments; `Arguments()`. Definitely some overthinking on my part. I will review the other information you had linked as well. Thank you!